# how to display all the mothods called in the codeigniter profiler

Tags: codeigniter-2

is there any way to display all the methods called in the codeigniter profiler.

Also like to display which method calls which method and which method trigger the query

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your question is not very clear to me. I am not really sure of what you want to do.

there is a PHP command available in later versions called debug-backtrace. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

this gives you the stack trace of all commands executed to get to a particular method.

The codeigniter profiler is a system library.  If there is a feature you really need it is possible to extend the profiler class to have the functionality you require.  the CI manual explains how to do this in the section about 'Extending Native Libraries'

Comment: When i load a page,i want the profiler to display all the functions called during the process.

After an hour googling, found netbeans xdebug profiling which is exactly giving what i want.

Thanks for your reply